# AS3 PNG Encoder without BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, scaleform

Simply stated, I'm looking for a PNG encoder that will directly convert a RGB/RGBA `ByteArray` into a PNG file also stored in a `ByteArray` without making use of the `BitmapData` class at all. I'm currently working on a ~v4.0 Scaleform Gfx project - which doesn't support any of the Get/SetPixel methods.

Comment: This? https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/codec/PNGEncoder.html#encodeByteArray()

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Scaleform 4.0, then likely your best solution is to bind the `ByteArray` in question to a `GFx::Value` in C++, via an `ExternalInterface` call. With the `GFx::Value`, you can use `ReadByteArray`, `WriteByteArray`, etc.

Scaleform 4.0 by default has a PNG reader/writer built in,  `Scaleform::Render::PNG::FileReader/FileWriter`. These basically just wrap `libpng` functionality. You can use `Scaleform::MemoryFile` to wrap the incoming/outgoing bytes, so they can use this interface.

Alternatively, if you'd like to use the `BitmapData` API, you could upgrade to the final version of Scaleform, which is available from Autodesk support for free, assuming you have a valid license.